# How do I output one node as XML

Tags: nodes, 6

I am creating a page flip for a drupal site using [pdf_to_imagefield](http://drupal.org/project/pdf_to_imagefield) module to export PDf to JPG and then I need to have the list of JPG files as XML to use them in [Dynaimc page flip](http://76design.com/shiftcontrol/2006/08/22/dynamic-page-flip-v2/).

The PDF and all JPOG files for each PDF page are stored in the same node of a certaine content type. How do I output this node as XML where I can control XML tags??

I have tried to create node-content-type.tpl.php but it comes as HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend that you use views as your source for the list of jpegs to output your XML file from. Using Views for example, I was able to make list of event images and make a custom XML file used to display the images in the Cub3r Flash plugin (I thought it was a bad idea but the client really wanted a Flash slideshow). I used the [Views Bonus Pack](http://drupal.org/project/views_bonus) export module, that gave me a style 'XML file'. I had only the image field, that was set to output the full image URL, the label I set it to was used as the custom tag. I then did an override of the XML template that came with the module and customized it to my needs (adding config parameters to cub3r).

Hopefully this will help you out. I also saw that the export module now has a [fork](http://drupal.org/project/views_data_export) that uses the batch API. Make sure you also checkout the [Views data source](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module.

Comment: yes that's really helping..thks

Answer (score 3):

You can make a [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu/6) entry for your XML URL w/ a callback function.

The callback function can do a

```
drupal_set_header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

// stuff to make the xml;

print $xml;

exit;
```

You can also do it with views, but I forget the steps to do this.  There are a bunch of tutorials on the net, though, that outline this method, and likely some questions/answers on the main SO site.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it by creating a module, which generates an xml-file when you update your node. I used `hook_update` to hook into the update progress, check if the images have been updated and create / update the config.xml which I store in the directory of the images.  this way you dont need to generate the xml file each time a user views the node.

You have to create a [template](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_theme/6) for generating the xml-files, passing your image-datasetting the configurations and than [save](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.fwrite.php) the [themed](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6) content into the config.xml.

hope I could help

Comment: This would mean that the XML file would bypass any permissions that may be in place on the node.

Comment: you wont parse the XML file if the node is not being viewed. but if there is need to protect the cfg-file you can still save the file in the private folder, create a path for xmlfile generation in your module where you can check the permissions and embed this generation path with the parameters you need (node, user etc)